# Is there any point to having multiple CW answers on the same post?

Tags: discussion

Is there any point to having multiple Community Wiki answers on the same post? For example [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/3558/14666) & [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/3576/14666) at [Is there an online sample sentence database or search engine](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/3557/14666)? It seems to me that having multiple answers defeats the purpose of Community Wiki.

Comment: Yes. You can see them, no?

Comment: However, that appears to me to defeat the purpose. (That should have been part of the original question anyway.) @MattЭллен My question was more in the sense of '(How) can ...'. (No, don't say "like in the example you have").

Comment: You should edit your question to reflect what you actually want to ask. If you want to know "Is there any point to having more than one CW answer?" you should ask that.

Comment: This is status-by-design since day one. I see your point, but here's an extremely simple (and very common) scenario: let's say you convert a question into CW that already has several answers. Do you expect the system to randomly throw away all of them but one?

Comment: @RegDwighт Rather, I'd expect that multiple wikis would get merged. However, it seems that was not intended to be for some good reason.

Comment: Thanks @Marthaª for the edit. Yes, that's in fact what I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [Is there an online sample sentence database or search engine?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/3557) it is the question that was made a Community Wiki, and all the answers were automatically made Community Wiki as well. In that case, it happens for a specific reason.

In other cases, it doesn't make any sense to limit the CW answers to one per question. I could make my answer CW because I don't want to get any reputation for it, or because it is not complete, and I want to give to somebody else the opportunity of improving it. For example, I could write an answer reporting what said in a comment, and (not wanting reputation for something written by another user) make it CW.
The fact I preferred to make my answer CW should not limit the possibility for other users to do the same, also because CW answers are not containers where different users add completely different answers.

There is also another reason for allowing multiple CW answers: When an answer has been edited from the author X times, or from Y users, it is automatically converted in CW answer. If there is a limit of one CW answer per question, it would mean that those answers should be merged together, and this is not what should happen, for what I previously said.

Comment: "because CW answers are not containers where different users add completely different answers." -- that says it all! Thank you so much.